# How to avoid a circular reference in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to create two different classes that represent different options of exercises the user can choose to sort by.  After one class is chosen, the other is no longer an option, because of this I create an ArrayList in both classes of classes which are not allowed to follow it.

The problem is that since they are not able to follow each other, when these classes are constructed it results in an infinite loop, is there any way I can avoid this?

PushPullLegs Class

```
public class PushPullLegs extends SortingGroup implements Serializable{
    public PushPullLegs(){
        this.setName("Push,Pull,Legs");
        this.addCantFollow(new MuscleGroup());

        SortingCategory push = new SortingCategory("Push","PPL","Push");
        this.addOption(push);
        SortingCategory pull = new SortingCategory("Pull","PPL","Pull");
        this.addOption(pull);
        SortingCategory legs = new SortingCategory("Legs","PPL","Legs");
        this.addOption(legs);        
    }
}
```

MuscleGroup Class

```
public class MuscleGroup extends SortingGroup implements Serializable {
    public MuscleGroup(){
        this.addCantFollow(new PushPullLegs());
        SortingCategory chest = new SortingCategory("Chest","Primary","Chest");
        chest.addNewOptions(new ChestMovementPatterns());
        this.addOption(chest);
        SortingCategory triceps = new SortingCategory("Triceps","Primary","Triceps");
        triceps.addNewOptions(new TricepMovementPatterns());
        this.addOption(triceps);
        SortingCategory lats = new SortingCategory("Lats","Primary","Lats");
        this.addOption(lats);
        SortingCategory quads = new SortingCategory("Quads","Primary","Quads");
        this.addOption(quads);
        SortingCategory hamstrings = new SortingCategory("Hamstrings","Primary","Hamstrings");
        this.addOption(hamstrings);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't do it by instance, do it by class, i.e. `this.addCantFollow(MuscleGroup.class);`

Comment: Ok thank you, currently my addCantFollow method constructor is: 
 protected void addCantFollow(SortingGroup cf).   What should I change the cf parameter to when passing in a class?

Comment: @Andreas so I guess I'm asking what type of variable I can store the .class files I pass in as?

Comment: There's a type called `Class` and each class has a field called `class` that contains it's own class type. Your method could take a `Class` parameter like this `public void addCantFollow(Class sortingGroupClass)` and you would call it like `addCantFollow(MuscleGroup.class)`.

Comment: Please post an [mcve] that shows the actual problem with infinite loops

Comment: @jameslarge: he has infinite recursion in the ctors: ctor for `A` calls `new B` and ctor for `B` calls `new A` hence the advice to use the (single, pre-existing) `Class` object instead of an instance

Comment: D'Oh!  Comment retracted.

Answer (score 1):

You would use code like this:

```
private Set<Class<? extends SortingGroup>> cantFollowClass = new HashSet<>();

public void addCantFollow(Class<? extends SortingGroup> clazz) {
    this.cantFollowClass = clazz;
}

public boolean canFollow(SortingGroup group) {
    return ! this.cantFollowClass.contains(group.getClass());
}
```